# Can anyone chant Langulopanishad?

Tags: vedas, rama, upanishads, hanuman

Salutations to everyone and the one who encompasses all!
I recently stumbled upon something called Langulopanishad which is an integral part of Atharvana Veda. By birth I'm a sudra so I'm not that familiar about the vedas and their knowledge. I've recently started Hanuman chalisa chant for some benefits. One day I've read something about Langulopanishad in Instagram. I've heard it twice in YouTube. Now I wan to learn how to chant it. But it has a lot of Beejaksharas. I wanted to know if there are any restrictions to chant this particular Upanishad or anyone can chant this.

Comment: Beeja Mantras are Tantric - meaning they need to be learned from a guru. Just as you cannot learn songs from lyrics without listening to them, the same is true with the case of Beeja Mantras. Best you can do is to get over something that is not inclined towards beeja mantras. This is my opinion.

Comment: Any Upanishad to be chanted needs strictly Guru agyna. And adding beejas to it, makes it further difficult to violate this rule.